# Measure of the union of strictly increasing measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory

The problem I was given is as follows:

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space.  Let $\{A_i\}$ be a strictly increasing sequence of inclusions on $\mathcal{A}$, i.e., 
        $$ A_1 \subset A_2 \subset \cdots \subset A_i \subset A_{i+1} \subset \cdots $$
        Prove that 
        $$ \mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right) = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\mu(A_N) $$
**My attempt at a proof:**
        $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right) = 
\mu\left(\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\bigcup_{i=1}^N A_i\right) = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^N A_i\right) = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\mu(A_N) \qquad \blacksquare$$

This seems too good to be true -- is the second equality justifiable?

Comment: Not posting as an answer because I'm working a lot of this myself at the moment, but I believe the second equality is fine. What concerns you about it?

Comment: I guess it would require that an arbitrary measure $\mu$ is continuous, would it not?

Comment: Define $E_n = A_n \setminus A_{n-1}$ and apply countable additivity to prove that equality.

Comment: Oh good idea! Thanks.

Comment: @MöbiusDickus you are quite right. I foolishly assumed we were talking about Lebesgue measure.